# How can i format log4j time to specific timezone?

Tags: java, spring-boot, timezone, log4j2

Below is my log4j2 layout :

```
layout = %d{DATE} %-5p - %m%n.
```

It'll print time in log as -> `2019-05-28 11:48:36,977 INFO  - Hello World.`

Which is my system datetime(IST),but I want to print log datetime in GMT format.

is it possible to format timezone in log4j2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

**To format date time in GMT please consider**

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss.SSS,GMT+0}
```

---

You can also change time zone by adding number after GMT for example:

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss.SSS,GMT+06}
```

for more check out this link: [Log4J Layouts](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout)

Comment: Thanks @ruhul

**%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}{GMT+0} %-5p - %m%n**

Solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a pattern in the appender, in example for the console appender:

```
<appenders>
    <Console name='Console' target='SYSTEM_OUT'>
        <PatternLayout pattern='%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n'/>
    </Console>
</appenders>
```

Check [their documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) at "Pattern Layout" section for all possible commands